# Раздача интернета через локальную сеть

Tags: сеть

Здравствуйте! Задача такая: есть сеть из 10 ПК, объединенных в сеть через сервер. Необходимо настроить раздачу интернета (3g модем), только на 5 из 10 компьютеров. Сервер выполняет ещё и функцию файл сервера. Необходимо ограничить доступ на ресурсы сервера через интернет, только для сети.

OS: `Windows 2003 server`.

Желательно, не используя дополнительный софт.

**UPD:**

Модем подключён к одному из клиент компьютеров. Модем мегафон 3G. На ПК прописаны статичные IP.

Answer (score 1):

Настраиваем [NAT](http://www.netdocs.ru/articles/Configuring-Windows-Server-2003-act-NAT-router.html), на локальных машинах, которым не нужен доступ в Инет не указываем шлюз и днс.

Comment: а можно по подробней, пробовал всяко, не получаеться

Comment: Модем втыкаем в 2003 сервер, на нем настраиваем NAT, для всех остальных он становится шлюзом (gateway), кому инет не нужен, у тех шлюз и днс не указываем.

Answer (score 0):

Если устраивает вариант смены ОС, то на этом дистрибутиве можно и траффик фильтровать и файл сервер сделать, да в общем все, что хочешь можно сделать - [zentyal.org](http://zentyal.org) Рекомендую попробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Очень не рекомендую раздачу инета локальным сервером, тем более сервером с виндой. Перед вами классическая задача, которая решается отдельным интернет-шлюзом. Вариантов масса, начиная от терминального сервера, заканчивая дистрибутивом zentyal. В противном случае, ваш сервер рано или поздно будет хранилищем всех видов вирусов, плюс к этому вы получите утечку данных и как последняя капля - ваш сервер умрет! Стремитесь быть профессионалами!

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый, ставьте прокси и не парьтесь. Не важно, отдельный он будет (железный) или софтовый. Все проблемы ваши тут же решаться. Варинатов у вас куча. Запрос "Прокси для Windows 2003" даст массу результатов. Обратите внимание на UserGate. Решение очень давнее, платное, но не дорогое (особенно, если это для конторы). И не бойтесь никаких вирусов. Они и без интернета к вам придут :)